# How to download adminer with wget?

Tags: php, webserver

The [Adminer homepage](https://www.adminer.org/) says:

> Latest stable version (use e.g. by wget):
>   https://www.adminer.org/latest[-mysql][-en].php

I tried to download it with:

```
wget -p /var/www/html https://www.adminer.org/latest[-mysql][-en].php
```

I get an error:

> ERROR 404: Not Found.

Why the download fails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-mysql` and `-en` portions are optional:

```
wget https://www.adminer.org/latest.php
```

will download the latest version,

```
wget https://www.adminer.org/latest-en.php
```

will download the latest version in English only,

```
wget https://www.adminer.org/latest-mysql.php
```

will download the latest version for MySQL,

```
wget https://www.adminer.org/latest-mysql-en.php
```

will download the latest version for MySQL in English only.